# Does Dart support PHP like $_SESSION (sessions)?

Tags: dart

Does server side Dart support sessions like in PHP:

```php
<?php

session_start();

$_SESSION['fruit'] = 'apple';
```

The data is kept upon page loads.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes Dart has support for sessions which are more or less like in PHP.

Let's write a simple program that randomizes a fruit between apples and bananas and saves the choice to the session.

```dart
import 'dart:io';
import 'dart:math';

// A method that returns "apple" or "banana" randomly.
String getRandomFruit() => new Random().nextBool() ? 'apple' : 'banana';

main() {
  var server = new HttpServer();

  server.defaultRequestHandler = (HttpRequest req, HttpResponse res) {
    // Initialize session with an empty {} object as data.
    var session = req.session((s) => s.data = {});

    // Save fruit to session if there is nothing in there.
    if (session.data['fruit'] == null)
      session.data['fruit'] = getRandomFruit();

    // Retrieve fruit from the session.
    var fruit = session.data['fruit'];

    res.outputStream.writeString("Your fruit: $fruit", Encoding.UTF_8);
    res.outputStream.close();
  };

  server.listen('127.0.0.1', 80);
}
```

Now when you run the code and go to `http://localhost`, every time you see the same fruit as long as the session stays open, because we save the fruit to the session.

Notes:

- The [`HttpRequest`](http://api.dartlang.org/docs/bleeding_edge/dart_io/HttpRequest.html) class has this method [`session()`](http://api.dartlang.org/docs/bleeding_edge/dart_io/HttpRequest.html#session) which initializes (or returns) the [`HttpSession`](http://api.dartlang.org/docs/bleeding_edge/dart_io/HttpSession.html) instance.
- The [`HttpSession`](http://api.dartlang.org/docs/bleeding_edge/dart_io/HttpSession.html) has a property called `data`, but you might want to initialize it first to be an empty `{}`.