# Is there anything like php session concept in dart?

Tags: php, session, dart

I am working in dart server side, need to create php session like concept in dart, so I dont know where to strat? suggest some link or concepts?

Comment: You can see this answer hope it may be helpful [enter link description here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14011500/does-dart-support-php-like-session-sessions)

Comment: yes thanks, I already seen it, Is there any documentation for session in dart. one like is not loading 'https://api.dartlang.org/136114/index.html#session'

Comment: Duplicate of [Does dart support php like sessions](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14011500/does-dart-support-php-like-session-sessions)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know what PHP's session is capable of but for Dart there are packages like https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/shelf_auth and https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/shelf_auth_session